How can it be that the moderation analisys is not significant but at +- 1 sd of the simple slope analysis all slopes are?
I'm currently working on some preliminary data (185 subjects).
I'm using moderation analysis with jamovi medmod package, 10000 bootstraps, continuous calculated variables (mean of items from a survey).
    Moderation estimates
                  Estimate  SE   Z     p
    Predictor     0.489  0.1051  4.65 <.001
    Moderator    -0.147  0.0976 -1.50 0.133
    Interaction  -0.170  0.1024 -1.66 0.096
   
    Simple slope analyses - Effect of the predictor for different levels of the moderator:
                Estimate SE    Z      p
    Average     0.489   0.106 4.63  <.001
    Low (-1SD)  0.649   0.143 4.53  <.001
    High (+1SD) 0.329   0.143 2.29  0.022

I don't get why the simple slope analysis yields significant results when the overall interaction does not.
I'm not that into the significant/not-significant discussion, but my collegues are.
I've seen people dealing with non-parametric analyses doing post-hoc analyses with an overall non-significant interaction effect, with categorical variables, and commenting the results.
How can it be that the overall moderation is NS and the simple slope analysis is significant? Is reasonable to expect significant interaction effect with this sample doubled?

There really isn't anything puzzling here.
The slope analysis is testing whether the slope is non-zero at three levels of the moderator and it is finding that it is significant at all three. The interaction is testing whether the slopes are different at different levels and finding that they are not significantly different. However, the slope analysis shows that the slopes are different, just not significantly so (at least, not at p = 0.05).

Now i get it.  Thanks
